# REST based message queue for microservices

Tags: java, activemq-classic, message-queue, microservices

I'm given a task to implement Message queue to publish and consume message over queue but my requirement is, i'm gonna need to interact with queue using REST API (eg: ActiveMQ having REST API but problem with ActiveMq is when implementing consumer  we don't have way to keep waiting for message queue to fetch,we cant listen to the queue using REST client ).
So  i'm leaving my problem to you guys to give me better alternative for this 
NOTE - solution should use only open source product only

Comment: Do you need to receive messages on an HTTP endpoint and put them on queue? Is that what you want?

Comment: somewhat correct but i  need to trigger HTTP end point once message on queue to consume message from HTTP end point (we can have JMS listener(Spring) in TCP connection but not in HTTP end point)

Comment: "So i'm leaving my problem to you guys" - your question deserves closing right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are describing is the fundamental difference between messaging (stateful connections) and http-based services (stateless). A stateful consumer can process messages, b/c the broker knows the connection is active. This is also known as a "push" semantic. HTTP-based services are "pull". WebSockets provide a level of "push" available to web-browsers, but in the end you are really just doing STOMP or MQTT over WebSockets.

If you are doing a web application, look to web sockets. If it is a backend application go JMS+Openwire.

Comment: Don't forget AMQP over WebSockets  ;)

Comment: Good point, Tim =)  We've almost reached 'anything over everything' ;-)

Comment: really I'm newbie for this messaging /STOM/MQTT/AMQP and all.Could u able elaborate more this solution you all proposing with given technology like where can i use this tech to achieve my requirement  and how can i achieve using which architect